# Change current working directory for each module in a reactor build?

Tags: java, spring, maven

As far as I have found, Maven *cannot* change the current working directory for every module build in a reactor build (to the module that is being built) because it is *not* possible in standard Java to change the current working directory. First of all, is this correct?

If yes, how can I make the following scenario work?

**UPDATE:** I have a **some.properties** file that is supposed to be on the classpath of the module being built (e.g. in src/main/resources) and it is being referred to in a Spring context file of a *Maven Plugin*, like this:

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <array>
                <value>classpath:some.properties</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The Maven Plugin is being executed in "process-test-resources" phase. Also, some.properties file has a property that refers to an external **relative** configurable path:

```
some.spring.config.dir=target/test-classes
```

Then, a few config files from this path are loaded in spring context files in the module being built, such as:

```
<property name="configLocation" value="file:${some.spring.config.dir}/cache.xml" />
```

This scenario works when I build the project from its pom.xml directory but **not** when I build it as part of a reactor build from a top level directory. Is there a way to get it working when **running maven from any directory** and also keep the path in my properties file (e.g. "target/test-classes") **relative**?

Comment: In my experience, the CWD of unit tests is always changed to the module directory, even in a reactor build. I have many testcases referring to a relative location in src/test/resources. So  I wonder, at which path of the build cycle do you face this problem?

Comment: According to my findings, the relative paths would be resolved by Maven if they are specified in the pom file but if you use the File class to load a string path, it remains relative to mvn working directory.

Comment: In unit test classes, I can definitely use something like new File("src/test/resources/myModuleFile.txt") and it correctly resolves relative to the module directory and not to the directory in which I originally invoked mvn. However, if you fill properties in your pom.xml file using variables such as ${project.basedir}, it may be different. Does your problem occur while running tests using the surefire plugin, or during some other phase of the build?

Comment: I updated the question to include phase information. Thanks for your followup.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps required:

1. Include resource filtering for configuration file: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html
2. in configuration file add basedir:

   ```
     some.spring.config.dir=${basedir}/target/test-classes
   ```

   In "target" directory "some.spring.config.dir" will be filled with full path.

Comment: The question was about maintaining **relative** paths.

Comment: Proposed solution worked for path relative to working dir, all fine

Comment: I have tried this solution and it does not work because ${basedir} is mapped to the plugin module directory.